# SignalR specify an url for external react client server in Web API .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, reactjs, signalr, webapi

I'm using Web API .NET Framework Web API and React.js on a different client server. I searched on the internet how can I link my client server with my SignalR from the API but I could not find anything that will work for me.
Here's what I've done in my API:

```
    using System;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.Owin;
    using Owin;

    [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(orar__.Startup))]

    namespace orar__
    {
    public class Startup
    {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit 
    https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
        
        app.MapSignalR();

    }
    }
    }
```

Then I used a SignalR Hub Class (v2):

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;
    using orar__.Models;

    namespace orar__
    {
    [HubName("HubSignalR")]
    public class HubSignalR : Hub
    {

    /// <summary>
    /// Send element to all users
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="element"></param>
    public void SendElement(Element_orar element)
    {
    IHubContext context = 
    GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext("HubSignalR");
    context.Clients.All.pushNewElement(
    element.Body,



    element.Description,
    element.EndTime ,
    element.Eveniment ,
    element.Id ,
    element.ForeignLanguage ,
    element.Class,
    element.Specialization ,
    element.Teacher,
    element.Year ,
    element.ClassRoom,
    element.StartTime ,
    element.Subject,
    element.Group
    );
    }

    }
    }
```

And my class element:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;

    namespace orar__.Models
    {
    public class Element_orar
    {
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public bool Eveniment { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool ForeignLanguage { get; set; } 
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public int Specialization { get; set; } //ownerid
    public string Teacher { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; } //roomid
    public string ClassRoom { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }//otherdataid
    }
    }
```

I don't know if it works yet. If it's possible I want to know how to make a link for my SignalR in API. Something like: "app.MapSignalR("https://localhost:44376/signalr");" inside Startup.cs in order to call the connection from my client server to that link.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by using the configuration below:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {  
        // Branch the pipeline here for requests that start with "/signalr"
        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            // Setup the CORS middleware to run before SignalR.
            // By default this will allow all origins. You can configure the set of origins and/or http verbs by providing a cors options with a different policy.
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
            {
                // You can enable JSONP by uncommenting line below.
                // JSONP requests are insecure but some older browsers (and some versions of IE) require JSONP to work cross domain
                EnableJSONP = true,
                EnableDetailedErrors = true,
                EnableJavaScriptProxies = true
            };

            // Run the SignalR pipeline. We're not using MapSignalR since this branch already runs under the "/signalr" path.
            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        });
   }
}
```

This will allow you to work with **cross domain** clients like mine (the react app is on **localhost:3000** and the api is on **localhost:44384** in my case).

On my React application I used a package without Jquery which you can find here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/signalr-no-jquery
To make a connection you will have to use a link like this:
`'http://[address]:[port]/signalr/hubs'`
or https if you use a secure connection.